# JSON data undefined

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

I am having a little problem with the JSON data.

I can trace the event.target.data. But when i parse it into an Array, i can't display it, and it just shows up as undefined. Wondering what is happening, thanks for your time

```
Send1 = new URLRequest("http://localhost/Accountinfo.php");
            Send1.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            ALoader1 = new URLLoader();
            ALoader1.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            ALoader1.load(Send1);
            ALoader1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,Sandler1);

      function Sandler1 (event:Event):void{

          var resultString2 :String = event.target.data;
// parse result string as json object and cast it to array

           var resultArray2  :Array  = JSON.parse( resultString2 ) as Array;

          trace(event.target.data);
          trace(resultArray2.username);

        }
```

Thanks for your time!

JSON result:

```
[{"id":"174","username":"yahoo","password":"241fe8af1e038118cd817048a65f803e","email":"yahoo","phone":"123","bed1":"tr","Zip1":"tr","rangelow1":"tr","rangehigh1":"tr","bed2":"fesff","Zip2":"sef","rangelow2":"sef","rangehigh2":"fse"}]
undefined
```

Comment: For me `JSON.parse( resultString2 ) as Array` always return `null`. why exactly you need this type casting?

Comment: Hi i attached the JSON data, and the trace for the resultarray.username. I just need to separate the JSON data, and then put that into an array, such as info:new Array(resultArray2[0],resultArray2[1]); etc so then set that as public static var and then parse it to another class.

Comment: try `trace(resultArray2[0].username);`

Comment: It gives you an array. So you need to query specific element and get it's properties (your array has one element)..

Comment: Sweet it works, i thought i did do that before... maybe i had a long day. Thanks everything for your help, really appreciate it!